# React: Cannot read property 'times' of undefined Although "times" is defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

There is a strange behavior going on with my application. I have the following DatePicker as follows:

```
  <DatePicker
  inline
  minDate={moment().add(1, "day").utc().toDate()}
  maxDate={moment().add(7, "day").utc().toDate()}
  selected={selectedDate ? selectedDate : moment().utc().toDate()}
  onChange={this.onDateSelect}/>
```

If I leave the code as such, the application runs fine, but if I change the minDate from 1 to -say- 25 and then maxDate from 7 to 35, then I get the above error on this line of code:

The following is in the reducer with an initialState defined as:

```
const initialState = {
    days: [],
    times:[],
    schedule: {},
    rescheduled: false
};

  > let times = dayList.find(day => Boolean(day.selected) === true).times.filter(time => Boolean(time.available) === true);
```

I am just not sure why `times` becomes undefined if it is clearly defined in here?

Any feedback or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That makes no sense, what is `X`?

Comment: Just read the title: "cannot read property 'X' of undefined" means that you try `something.X`, where `something` is undefined.

Comment: Yes, but the debugger points at let X not something.X ? This is why it is confusing! Also, the application works fine. It stops working only if I change the min and max dates

Comment: @kind user X is an array that gets available days from an API in the reducer!

Comment: Please consider changing names of variables to some more readable. Right now it's really confusing. If X is a reducer, than there's something wrong with state. Provide complete code.

Comment: Include a minimal, reproducible example of your problem

Comment: I have edited my code to include my initialState and gave a better naming to the variable that is undefined. The issue is why would it stop working only if I change the minDate and maxDate to something in the far future?

Comment: there are almost 7000 questions for [\[javascript\] title:"cannot read property"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+title%3A%22cannot+read+property%22), none of them helped?

Answer (score 2):

If `Array#find` function does not "find" anything - it returns undefined.

Apparently that's why you are getting the error:

```
dayList.find(day => Boolean(day.selected) === true).times
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-> undefined
```

I would suggest to you make sure that `times` is not undefined:

```
const getTimes = (dayList) => {
   const time = dayList.find(day => Boolean(day.selected) === true);

   if (time && Array.isArray(time.times)) {
      return time.times.filter(n => Boolean(n.available) === true);
   }
};
```

**Note**: You should also check if `time.times` is an array, to properly use `Array#filter` on that.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not saying that `times` is undefined.  It's saying that it can't read the `times` property of an `undefined` object. If you had a variable called `entry` and then you say `entry.times` that will work only if `entry` is defined as an object.  But you'll get this error if you do this:

```
let entry;
entry.times = [];  // <-- fails because entry is undefined
```

Looking at your code, you have this:

```
dayList.find(day => Boolean(day.selected) === true).times.filter(time => Boolean(time.available) === true);
```

So I'm guessing that the part before `.times` is evaluating as `undefined`.  By this I mean

```
dayList.find(day => Boolean(day.selected) === true)  ===  undefined
```

You didn't give enough information to know what kind of objects are in the `dayList` array, but if `dayList.find()` could not find anything, it will return `undefined` and then your attempt to access `undefined.times` will cause the error you see.

I recommend splitting this line up into separate parts so you can only try to access data that you know is present.  For example:

```
const item = dayList.find(day => Boolean(day.selected) === true);
if (item) {
  const times = item.times;
  // do something with the times array...
}
else // report that no day could be found, or whatever is appropriate
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be confusing [ReferenceError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) that happens in strict mode when you forget to declare a variable, e.g. `console.log(iDontExist)`.

However, the [Property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) (dot operator in `obj.property`) returns value `undefined` when the property of an object does not exist, e.g.

```
const obj = {property: 1}
console.log(obj.iDontExist) // undefined
```

The problem is, `undefined` itself does not behave the same, it throws an error when you try to access `undefined.property`, e.g.:

```
const obj = {property: 1}
console.log(obj.iDontExist.whatever) // ???
```

The error is different in different JS implementations though, e.g. in Firefox:

```
TypeError: obj.iDontExist is undefined
```

In Chrome and Node.js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'whatever' of undefined
```

In Edge:

```
Unable to get property 'whatever' of undefined or null reference
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  > let x = dayList.find(day => Boolean(day.selected) === true).times.filter(time => Boolean(time.available) === true);
```

Here you chain properties left and right. It would be much easier to answer if you said which property is giving you trouble instead of saying 'X'.

Probably the .find() method is not finding anything at some point and when you access .times it says the result of .find() is undefined, or maybe .times.filter().

Every time you use .find() you should store the result in a variable and check that it has a value before trying to do anything with it.